# How to set variable in Linux environment

Tags: linux, path, adb

Everytime i have to set ADB path as

```
ADB=/home/amir/Android_sdk/platform-tools/adb scrcpy
```

is alternative to update in path so i can use directly this adb for scrcpy

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question gives very less context. Please have a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put it inside `.bashrc` file, so it runs every time you start your bash.